Why is setRotation() not working in my Sprite in LibGDX?
Although the code seems right, for some reason in the game the sprite doesnt visibly rotate towards the cursor, it doesnt rotate at all
Texture playerTexture;
Sprite playerSprite;
Vector3 playerPos = new Vector3();

public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    playerTexture = new Texture("playerAiming.png");
    playerSprite = new Sprite(playerTexture);
    playerSprite.setOrigin(playerSprite.getWidth() / 2, playerSprite.getHeight() / 2);
}

public void render () {
    
    float speed = playerSpeed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    float mouseX = Gdx.input.getX();
    float mouseY = Gdx.input.getY();
    float playerX = playerPos.x + playerSprite.getWidth() / 2;
    float playerY = playerPos.y + playerSprite.getHeight() / 2;
    float angle = MathUtils.atan2(mouseY - playerY, mouseX - playerX) * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;

    playerSprite.setRotation(angle); //Doesnt work for some reason
    ScreenUtils.clear(1, 0, 0, 1);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(playerSprite, playerPos.x, playerPos.y);
    batch.end();
    //Movement codes and others...
}

The variables are working just fine(i sysod them), i tried using straight up Texture and also wouldnt work

It does not rotate because you are using the method on SpriteBatch that draws TextureRegions and that needs parameters for position and rotation passed and you are only passing position.
Sprite extends TextureRegion so when you call
batch.draw(playerSprite, playerPos.x, playerPos.y);

you are using a function that does not know of the properties of the Sprite, if you instead use
playerSprite.draw(batch);

The draw call will respect the rotation of the Sprite.
The reason the rotation is wrong is because you are calculating the smallest angle so it wraps around at 180 degrees.
Another way of doing this would be to create a Vector2 that represents the direction from the player to the mouse, and then use the angleDeg function on Vector2 to get the angle out, thus delegating the calculation to code already in libGDX.
For example:
    SpriteBatch batch;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    Texture playerTexture;
    Sprite playerSprite;
    Vector2 playerPos = new Vector2();

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        float aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        float w = 640;
        float h = w / aspectRatio;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(w, h);
        playerTexture = new Texture("player.png");
        playerSprite = new Sprite(playerTexture);
        playerSprite.setOrigin(playerSprite.getWidth() / 2, playerSprite.getHeight() / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Vector2 mousePositionScreen = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
        Vector3 unprojectedMousePosition = camera.unproject(new Vector3(mousePositionScreen, 1.0f));
        Vector2 mousePositionWorld = new Vector2(unprojectedMousePosition.x, unprojectedMousePosition.y);
        Vector2 playerToMouse = new Vector2();

        playerToMouse.set(mousePositionWorld).sub(playerPos); // This is the vector from the player to the mouse

        playerSprite.setRotation(playerToMouse.angleDeg()); // Get the angle of the vector

        ScreenUtils.clear(Color.BLACK);
        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        playerSprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

This example is slightly different from yours as it uses a Camera but that is just because I find it easier to scale the view that way.

Now it is rotating but unfortunately not properly, it follows the cursor in some points, but most of the time it is wrong

@Jeipi That is a different question, you will be more likely to get a good answer on stackoverflow if each post has one distinct question.  I'll update my answer with a fix for the actual rotation as well.
